# Kusto: Find where a specific column is not distinct based on a condition

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Dataset of URL fetches:-

```
datatable(Id:string, Datetime:datetime, URL:string, country:string)
[
    '1', datetime(2018-10-16 00:00), 'URL1',
    '1', datetime(2018-10-16 00:01), 'internal-url-predefined',
    '2', datetime(2018-10-16 00:02), 'URL2',
    '3', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'URL3',
    '4', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'URL4',
    '4', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'internal-url-predefined',
]
```

For some request IDs, like `1` and `4`, we have two rows.

How do I find `per-unit-time`. , how many times we have a case where `url == internal-url-predefined` when there's `another row with same Id`

Pseudocode I want to achieve:-

- Find all rows that don't have `distinct Id`. So, the answer is `1` and `4`.

  ```
  | where <<my_other_custom_conditions>>
  | summarize count() by Id
  | where count_ > 1
  ```
- In the above match of `Id`s that we'll get, find which of those have `URL == "internal-url-predefined"`, per unit time.

  ```
  ?? How do I reuse the result of previous dataset to match 
  rows that have URL == "internal-url-predefined" ??
  ```

What is the feature of Kusto that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I asked too early and I should have known `materialize` operator which is a way to store results of one query and use it in the next query.

```
let dataset=datatable(Id:string, Datetime:datetime, URL:string)
[
    '1', datetime(2018-10-16 00:00), 'URL1',
    '1', datetime(2018-10-16 00:01), 'internal-url-predefined',
    '2', datetime(2018-10-16 00:02), 'URL2',
    '3', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'URL3',
    '4', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'URL4',
    '4', datetime(2018-10-16 00:03), 'internal-url-predefined',
];
let _duplicate_ids = materialize(dataset | summarize count() by Id | where count_ > 1 | project Id);
_duplicate_ids
| join kind=inner (dataset) on Id
| where URL == "internal-url-predefined"
| summarize count() by bin(Datetime, 1s)
```

Result:-

```
2018-10-16T00:01:00Z    1
2018-10-16T00:03:00Z    1
```

Comment: **(1)** You are not reusing `_duplicate_ids`, therefore there is no reason to use `materialize` **(2)** The default JOIN kind is `innerunique` which takes only one row per JOIN key, from the left side, which in this case is already unique.

Comment: **(2)**Thanks, Updated the answer with `kind=inner`

**(1)** I've used materialize because in the actual more complex query, I'm filtering data by time and I wanted the dataset to be same when performing the `join`. Is that a suitable way? @DavidדודוMarkovitz